# how to update single field in database, django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

**Model.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ClientDetails(models.Model):

    objects = models.Manager()
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    Mobile_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def __str__(self):
       return self.username

  class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'ClientDetail'
       verbose_name_plural = 'ClientDetails'
```

**forms.py file** using this form i am storing the users data user

```
from django.forms import models
from django import forms
from Client.models import ClientDetails

class ClientDetailsForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientDetails
        fields = ['Assignment','email','username','gender', 'Mobile_no', 'address','city','Joining_branch',
                    'Work_type','candidate_job_level', 'submission_date', 'submission_time',
                    'candidate_photo', 'created_by', 'amount_paid', 'name','fix_or_custom']
```

**AdminPanel/create_account.html** this file is from AdminPanel/templates which **creates** the user and also store the data into **ClientDeatils**

```
<form action="{% url 'AdminPanel:fixed_target_account'%}" method="POST" 

enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon fas fa-at text-black-50"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="username" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-user"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="name" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon fas fa-genderless"></i>
                    <select class="form-control text-dark" name="gender" style="border:1px solid gray" required="" id="id_gender">
                        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

                        <option value="Male">Male</option>

                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon fas fa-mobile-alt"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="Mobile_no" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Mobile No.">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="address" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Address">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon far fa-map"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="city" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="City">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon fas fa-code-branch"></i>
                    <select class="form-control text-dark" name="Joining_branch" style="border:1px solid gray" required="" id="id_Joining_branch">
                            <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                            <option value="Bhandup West">Bhandup West</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-info-circle"></i>
                    <select class="form-control text-dark" name="Work_type" style="border:1px solid gray" required="" id="id_Work_type">
                        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                        <option value="CopyPaste">Copy Paste</option>
                        <option value="ODT">ODT</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-check-square"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="candidate_job_level" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Candidate job level">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-form"></i>
                    <select style="border:1px solid gray" class="form-control text-dark" name="Assignment" required="" id="id_Assignment">
                        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

                        <option value="Assignment 1">Assignment 1</option>

                        <option value="Assignment 2">Assignment 2</option>

                        <option value="Assignment 3">Assignment 3</option>

                        <option value="Assignment 4">Assignment 4</option>

                        <option value="Assignment 5">Assignment 5</option>

                        <option value="Assignment 6">Assignment 6</option>

                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="submission_date" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Submission Date">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon far fa-calendar-times"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="submission_time" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Submission time">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-mail"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="email" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Email ID">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-smile"></i>
                <input type="file" class="form-control text-dark" name="candidate_photo" style="border:1px solid gray" accept="image/*" required="" id="id_candidate_photo">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-user"></i>
                <select class="form-control text-dark" name="created_by" style="border:1px solid gray" required="" id="id_created_by">
                    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                    <option value="1">faijan</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='container' style="width:60%;">
            <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                <i class="prefix-icon fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-dark" name="amount_paid" style="border:1px solid gray" placeholder="Amount Paid">
            </div>
        </div>

        <select hidden name="fix_or_custom" required="" id="id_fix_or_custom">
            <option value="Fix" selected >Fix</option>
        </select>   

        <div class="text-center" style="content:50%;">
            <button class='btn btn-success btn-lg '>Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**AdminPanel/views.py** in this file I successfully created the user and stored the user data

```
def fixed_target_account(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClientDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['Mobile_no'])
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, 'AdminPanel/fixed_target_account.html', {'form':ClientDetailsForm,'error':"Username is already been taken."})
        if form.is_valid:
            newform = form.save(commit=False)
            newform.user = request.user
            newform.save()
            return redirect('AdminPanel:dashboard')
        else:
            return render(request, 'AdminPanel/fixed_target_account.html', {'form':ClientDetailsForm,'error':"Please enter the valid data."})
    else:
        pass

    return render(request, 'AdminPanel/fixed_target_account.html')
```

**Client/Views.py file** here I want when user logs in his **online** status should be set to true [even though it is]

```
def loginuser(request):
    ''' code for logging in the user also when logged in update staus to active '''
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        login(request, user)
        # get the id of the user 
        pk = request.user.id
        ClientDetails.objects.filter(id=pk).update(online=True)
        return redirect('Client:dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'Client/loginuser.html')
```

when he sign's out his **online** status should be set to False **I tried other ways and this as well but its not updating the status in backend [at admin side ]**

```
def sign_out(request):
    ''' before logging out the user update his online status to False '''
    pk = request.user.id
    print(pk)
    ClientDetails.objects.filter(id=pk).update(online=False)
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'Client/loginuser.html')
```

**loginuser.html file**

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between m-b-30">
            <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="{% static 'assets/images/logo/logo.png' %}">
            <h2 class="m-b-0">Sign In</h2>
        </div>
        <form action="{% url 'Client:login' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="font-weight-semibold" for="userName">Username:</label>
                <div class="input-affix">
                    <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="userName" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="font-weight-semibold" for="password">Password:</label>
                <a class="float-right font-size-13 text-muted" href="">Forget Password?</a>
                <div class="input-affix m-b-10">
                    <i class="prefix-icon anticon anticon-lock"></i>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <span class="font-size-13 text-muted">
                        Don't have an account? 
                        <a class="small" href=""> Signup</a>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here your ClientDetail model doesn't have any relation with the User model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ClientDetails` model isn't actually linked in any way to the model that's used for your user authentication. This model is probably called something like `User`, although we can't be certain of that with the given information in the question.

When you fetch the `id` of the currently authenticated user from the request with `request.user.id`, this is actually referencing a `User` instance and not a `ClientDetails` instance. So the line `ClientDetails.objects.filter(id=pk)` will most likely either give you the wrong `ClientDetails` instance or none at all and thus `update(online=True)` will normally not updated the instance you expect it to update.

So you either have to link your `ClientDetails` with a foreign key to your `User` object and then use that link to query, or you can presumably use the username from the `User` instance and use that in your query on `ClientDetails` like so: `ClientDetails.objects.filter(username=request.user.get_username())`.

Comment: arjun and @Glenn DJ sir ,pardon me for providing incomplete code I have updated code now please check now and guide me, thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes my answer still stands. Replace `ClientDetails.objects.filter(id=pk).update(online=True)` with either `ClientDetails.objects.filter(username=request.user.get_username()).update(online=True)` or `ClientDetails.objects.filter(username=request.POST['username']).update(online=True)`.

Comment: thank you sir , thank you so much it worked and You made my day. god bless you sir thank you again.